# Cannot pause HTML5 / Flash sound on Android in-app WebView when application going to background

Tags: android, html, flash, android-webview, chromium

Steps to reproduce the problem:

1. Start a application with a in-app WebView.
2. Call webview.loadUrl("http://n-g.nxtomo.hk/CYvsCP/app.html?nocache=true");
3. Click the web page once time and start to play a background music.
4. Press HOME button that the app will go to background, but the music keep playing.

**Expected the WebView being pause when the activity go to background.**

I've tried to call:

```
webview.onResume();
webview.onPause();
```

or

```
Class.forName("android.webkit.WebView").getMethod("onResume", (Class[]) null).invoke(webview, (Object[]) null);
Class.forName("android.webkit.WebView").getMethod("onPause", (Class[]) null).invoke(webview, (Object[]) null);
```

or

```
wv.resumeTimers();
wv.pauseTimers();
```

Both ways are not working (means no effect and keep playing sound in background) for Android 4.4.2 and 5.0 , I just have two devices.

And I found a suggestion is to remove the MediaPlayer's callback that force stop the sound play.

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        ((AudioManager) getSystemService(
                Context.AUDIO_SERVICE)).requestAudioFocus(
                null,
                AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT);
    }
```

It's work for stop the sound.
BUT! When I resume the app that the sound will not auto play continually. So, I'm looking for a officially way to fix this problem. :(

Refer to

1. [Issue 532359:   Cannot pause HTML5 sound on Android in-app WebView when application in background. - Sep 16, 2015] https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=532359
2. [Issue 10282:    Public API for WebView.onPause and WebView.onResume - Aug 7, 2010] https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10282

Comment: Are you restoring MediaPlayer's callback when your app returns back to foreground?

Comment: Umm.. no, but if i click the webpage again, it will continue play the previous sound. I don't know how to restore the MediaPlayer's callback for webview.

Comment: Is the HTML code in your control ?

Comment: Yeah, you can't restore the WebView's original callback, but you can try installing your own. I guess, it's the absence of an active callback in your activity that prevents it from producing a sound. I'm hoping that it doesn't matter what part of the activity has installed the callback -- your code or WebView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reply from Google:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=532359#c5

> Hm, if you only want to change the Android app, you're probably out of
>   luck with what you can do there.
>
> If you can change the page, you may look into page visibility API to
>   pause/resume playback (Tim may know if it's enabled for WebView or
>   not).
>
> But ultimately, since it's WebView, your app can communicate with the
>   page and cause it to play/pause playback in the app's activity
>   onPause/onResume.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem and looking for an official fix.
Only workaround I have found was to

> loadUrl("");

but it's far from a good fix. As soon as you multitask the page reloads, this can lead to a lot of problems if you need the webview session to be kept alive or persistent.

Comment: It's not a good practice. For normal web flow is ok but the game flow is not working cause the game state will be lost when you reload the url.

Comment: I was also facing the same issue in game.. Still now dint find any solution